# read image tags from html to js

Tags: javascript

i used the ***Conveyor Belt slideshow script*** from
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/leftrightslide.htm

In that the image tags are built in the script itself.

I want to get those images from html and put it in the script.

also it should be dynamic (the number for images)

Answer (score 0):

that script was last updated in 2004.  you might try looking for a more modern solution, like [this one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-jquery-image-scroller/)